# Help with a calendar

Tags: calendar

How do I set up a calendar that sends a notification when an event has been entered?

I do not seem to be able to change the form.

Answer (score 1):

We already have similar questions in this forum. It can be done using workflows. Please refer this.

[How can I get a Sharepoint calendar to send a notification email to users involved in an event?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16813/how-can-i-get-a-sharepoint-calendar-to-send-a-notification-email-to-users-involv)