# Send attendee a reminder email - workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

SP & SP Designer 2013, no Visio 2013, I have Visio 2010

When I create a calendar event I just want an email reminder to be sent to the Attendee(s). Don't know why this isn't an OOB function.

Yes, I looked at this forum, but it just says create it in SP Designer without saying how.
[How can I get a Sharepoint calendar to send a notification email to users involved in an event?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16813/how-can-i-get-a-sharepoint-calendar-to-send-a-notification-email-to-users-involv)

Can anyone please share the step by step process for creating this workflow in SharePoint (not in SP Designer) that will email a reminder to an Event Attendee prior to the event or as the event is created? I'd prefer to create the workflow within SP, because SP Designer is giving me errors around Visio. I am assuming this is because I have SP Designer 2013, but only have Visio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

There is no OTB solution. You could create a SharePoint workflow with a SP Designer. 
In Sharepoint Designer select the library you want to add the workflow to.

1.Click on "List Worklfow" on the ribbon

2.Provide a Name for your workflow

3.In the workflow designer setup your workflow:

a. Add Action "send email"

b. Specify the email parameters (Attendies field)

c. In the body field you can insert other values like Title etc by clicking on add or change lookup and add more actions as needed

4.Click on Workflow Settings in the Ribbon. Untick Allow this workflow to be started manually and enable on created and is changed.

5.Save the workflow (save button in the ribbon)

6.Publish the workflow (publish button in the ribbon)

Workflow should now be activated for that Library.
For more info [check the related question answer here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/77617/i-need-to-create-an-auto-generated-email-when-items-in-a-sharepoint-list-are-cre).

Or you can use a [third party alerting tools](http://blog.enovapoint.com/post/JungleBell-Mail-Merge-SharePoint-Alerts-from-Multiple-Lists).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the **alert** feature within the event itself. The label is "alert me", but you can add or delete users.
Of course if you want to do it programmatically, a workflow is the best solution.
No need of visio to build workflow.

Comment: Thanks Marpio,

The **Alert Me** only seems to send an alert if anything in the event **changes**, and there is no function to simply send a **reminder** to people that would be added to event attendees.

So it leads me to think I need a workflow. I have the **Attendees** box enabled in my Event, but how to programmatically send them a reminder using workflow (and if possible, only using SP, not SP Designer)?

Can you point me to a tutorial or this, or share some steps on how to add a simple attendee email reminder using a SharePoint workflow? 

Thanks

Comment: You cannot create workflows only in SP, you need anyway designer 2013. OOTB workflows are not really customizable.
I am not a programmer, SPD is very easy to use and is the only way to create useful workflows - if you cannot use Visual Studio. 
A workflow as the one you need is made with the condition that at a certain date (e g today-1) an email should be sent to certain addresses (attendees).